# TCST2300 Optical Sensor w/ Phototransistor Output - Rotary Encoder: Trying to Understand & Test

Tags: phototransistor

I'm trying to test a mechanical rotary encoder for a piece of industrial equipment.   I'll attach pictures, but basically the encoder operates by monitoring a slowly rotating perforated wheel. The perforations either open or obscure the line of sight between an infrared LED and a phototransistor.  There are two sensors and I assume that the two sensors placed in close proximity are used to detect the direction of motion.

The two sensors are Vishay TXST2300 (https://www.vishay.com/docs/81147/tcst2103.pdf) and are wired as per the attached diagram which I drew by using a Fluke meter in continuity  mode and literally diagraming the tracings on the board as best I can.  The problem is that the resulting circuit doesn't make sense to me so I either have: (a) incorrectly diagrammed the circuit, or (b) don't understand how the sensors are supposed to work.

I was expecting: (a) power (+5V DC) to all four "+" pins, (b) ground connected to the two "E"  pins in order to keep the infrared  LED's lit, and (c) separate signal lines to each of the "D" pins on the phototransistors.  Based on this expectation the 4-pin connector would have: (1) power, (2) ground, (3) signal a, and (4) signal b pins.

Instead, the "+" pin from each phototransistor goes to a dedicated pin on the 4-pin connector.  This would suggest 3 power pins and 1 ground on the 4-pin connector.

Again, I either (a) diagramed this incorrectly, or (b) don't understand how this is supposed to work, or (c) something I'm missing.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated - is my confusion related to a, b, or c?

Ironically, I purchased a couple TCST2300 sensors, wired one onto a breadboard along with an Arduino Uno (Rev 3) according to the TCST2300 test diagram in the data sheet and it worked perfectly which is why the wiring on the little PC board is so confusing.  I'll also attach pictures of the test circuit diagram from the data sheet and a screenshot of the output on a DS212 pocket oscilloscope - again, this test circuit appeared to work as I expected, but didn't add any insight into the circuit on the PC board I'm trying to test.

My goal is to: (a) identify the power and ground pin on the 4-pin connector so I can verify that the little PC board with the TSCT2300s is actually getting power from the mother board, and (b) ultimately design a test circuit so I can test the little PC board with the Arduino.

Thanks in advance - this one has got me stumped!

PS: I'm a self-trained hobbyist which probably explains some of my confusion!

[image: Front of Board - I've labelled the 4-pin connector pins]

[image: Back of Board with 4-pin connector (pins 1, 2, 3, 4 left to right)]

[image: Data Sheet Diagram of TCST2300 sensor]

[image: Derived Schematic using continuity tester - Doesn't make sense to me!]

[image: Data Sheet Test Circuit Diagram]

[image: DS212 Screen Shot of Test Circuit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test circuit is confusing you. As the PWB is designed, this is how to use it.

The output will be high when the beam is interrupted.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV3bWI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I know that the comments section aren't supposed to be used to express thanks, but I don't know any other way to say thanks!  This is a HUGE help to me!  Greatly appreciated Mattman944!